# How should I override a derived Bulma variable using SCSS?

Tags: sass, bulma

I'm using Bulma with Webpack 4. I'm trying to change the colour of button.is-primary to be pink instead of turquoise.

Here's the entire contents of my .scss file.

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600');

$body-size: 14px;
$primary: $pink;

@import "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

This is getting me the following error on build.

```
1>Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
1>
1>$primary: $pink;
1>         ^
1>      Undefined variable: "$pink".
```

Now, if I set $primary to be a specific hex colour it builds fine, so this issue seems to be because I'm trying to use the existing colour variable $pink. It does make sense to me that it hasn't been defined at that point, but the docs clearly say that I can add my overrides before importing Bulma, and their example does the same thing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: here's the documentation screen I'm looking at.

https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-webpack/

I note that in their example they do set new values for derived variables BUT only where they've redefined the intial value, like this...

```
$pink: #FA7C91;
```

If I change my .scss file as follows it does then compile and work as expected.

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600');

$body-size: 14px;
$pink: #FA7C91;
$primary: $pink;

@import "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

Comment: wouldn't moving the ```$body-size: 14px;
$primary: $pink;``` after importing bulma fix your issue?

Comment: and if $pink is not defnied, you'll need to set it somewhere, perhaps in a variables file

Comment: @clarenswd well, $pink is defined, in one of the files imported with Bulma. It totally makes sense to me that moving my $primary: $pink after the import statement would work, but it doesn't - and in the docs here https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/ it says "To override any of these variables, just set them before importing Bulma."

Comment: Can you show the css properties in the console for your button?
Do you see your color with line-through?
Some tips: firefox (or google) allow to display some more information on the dev version. Maybe you can download the dev version to see why it doesn't work?
follow this link: https://www.google.com/intl/fr/chrome/dev/ or this link https://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/developer/

Answer (score 1):

This should clarify things for you: https://versions.bulma.io/0.7.0/documentation/overview/customize/

```
// 1. Import the initial variables
@import "../sass/utilities/initial-variables";


// 2. Set your own initial variables (optional)
$pink: #ffb3b3;


// 3. Set the derived variables
// Use the new pink as the primary color
$primary: $pink;
```

Comment: Thanks, Friso - I had already tried this though, and it doesn't work. It's from the old version of the documentation so my guess is that it's been superseded. I get exactly the same error if I import initial-variables first.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot that I was importing Bulma via its compiled .css file.

Of course, you cannot override the Sass variables that way because after compilation they don't exist. To override Bulma's variables you need to import its .sass file(s), not its .css file.

Sharing in case anyone else makes the same mistake.